# How would you implement a save thread cooperation with signals in ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, signals, threadpool, synchronization

I just began to work with threads. I know the theory and understand the main aspects of it, but I've got only a little practice on this topic.

I am looking for a good solution (or pattern, if available) for the following problem.

> Assume there should be a transaction component which holds a pool of threads processing tasks from a queue, which is also part of this transaction component.
>
> Each thread of this pool waits until there's a task to do, pops it from the queue, processes it and then waits for the next turn.
>
> Assume also, there are multiple threads adding tasks to this queue. Then I want these threads to suspend until their tasks are processed.
>
> If a task is processed, the thread, which enqueued the processed task, should be made runnable again.

The ruby class `Thread` provides the methods `Thread#stop` and `Thread#run`. However, I read, that you should not use these methods, if you want a stable implementation. And to use some kind of signalling mechanism.

In ruby, there are some classes which deal with synchronization and thread cooperation in general like `Thread`, `Mutex`, `Monitor`, `ConditionVariable`, etc.

Maybe `ConditionVariable` could be my friend, because it allows to emit signals, but I'm just not sure.

How would you implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby provides a threadsafe `Queue` class that will handles some of this for you:

```
queue.pop
```

Will block until a value is pushed to the queue. You can have as many threads as you want waiting on the queue in this fashion. If one of the things you push onto the queue is another queue or a condition variable then you could use that to signal task completion.

Threads are notoriously hard to reason about effectively. You may find that an alternative higher level approach such as [celluloid](http://celluloid.io) easier to work with.